# Representation on square integrable sections of a principal bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, fibre-bundles

Let $X\rightarrow Y$ be a smooth principal $G$-bundle for some Lie group $G$. Then $L^2(X)$ has a natural $G$-action determined by fibrewise action of $G$ on $X$.

We have an abstract isomorphism of Hilbert spaces $L^2(X)\cong L^2(G)\otimes L^2(Y)$.

**Question:** Can we choose this isomorphism so that it extends to an isomorphism of $G$-representations, where $G$ acts on $L^2(G)$ by translation and on $L^2(Y)$ trivially?

I feel this should be true because $G$ acts only on the fibres of $X$ and not on the base $Y$, but I would be grateful if someone could provide a second opinion.

Comment: You are right, what I am asking really is question 2. I'll change the question accordingly.

Comment: Does $L^2(X)$ denote the space of $L^2$ functions on $X$, or $L^2$ sections of $X\to Y$?

Comment: There is an appendix in Zimmer's book "Erogodic theory semisiple groups ,...which says in particular that measure theoretically, every G bundle is trivial. For the trivial bundle your statement is obvious.

Comment: @ArunDebray $L^2(X)$ denotes the space of $L^2$ functions on $X$.